# Entity Framework and dynamic order by statements

Tags: sql, entity-framework-4.1

I have been struggling to get this working. I wish to have an EF statement take in a column to order by. My original statement was this:

```
var Query = from P in DbContext.People
                   where P.BusinessUnits.Any(BU =>BU.BusinessUnitID == businessUnitId)
                   orderby P.LastName
                   select P;
```

And I changed this to the following:

```
var Query = from P in DbContext.People
                   where P.BusinessUnits.Any(BU =>BU.BusinessUnitID == businessUnitId)
                   orderby sortField
                   select P;
```

Where `sortField` is the column we wish to sort on, and is a string i.e. `LastName`. However, it does not appear to work, it does no sorting, and the outputted SQL string is completely wrong. Anyone got this working before?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you could try passing  in an expression to your method with the following type:

```
Expression<Func<Person, object>> expr = p => p.LastName;
```

and then using linq extensions instead of linq expressions...

```
var Query = 
 DbContext.People
 .Where(P => P.BusinessUnits.Any(BU =>BU.BusinessUnitID == businessUnitId))
 .OrderBy(expr)
 .ToList();
```

Comment: Excellent answer, in this particular case, this seems a better solution so I will use this, thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to add in an "asc" and "desc" clause here?

Comment: Also, why would this work with string properties and not integers? One of the properties is an Int32, and when I try to sort in that order I get the error: "{"Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types."}"

Comment: Getting error for datetime type `Unable to cast the type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.Object'`

Answer (score 4):

Your sort does not work because you are sorting on a string literal. It is not illegal, but it is not particularly useful either. You need to provide a sorting field through the API of `IQueryable<T>`, for example, like this:

```
var q = from P in DbContext.People
   where P.BusinessUnits.Any(BU =>BU.BusinessUnitID == businessUnitId)
   orderby P.LastName
   select P;
if ("sortField".Equals("FirstName"))
    q = q.OrderBy(p => p.FirstName);
else if ("sortField".Equals("LastName"))
    q = q.OrderBy(p => p.LastName);
else if ("sortField".Equals("Dob"))
    q = q.OrderBy(p => p.Dob);
```

Comment: Good answer. In this particular case I am using BobTodd's answer, however I will keep this in mind for some of the dynamic queries I will be building soon.